# How to increase scroll back buffer on Paramiko SSH client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, terminal, paramiko

I use Paramiko to ssh to a server and want to list an output. But it only shows half of the output. There is a `--More--` at the end of output. How can I increase the buffer to show a full output?

Below is part of my scripts:

```
SERVER_ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
SERVER_ssh.load_system_host_keys()

SERVER_ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

try:
    SERVER_ssh.connect(hostname=SERVER_PLATFORM, port=SERVER_SSH_PORT, username=SERVER_ID, password=SERVER_PASSWORD)

except (AttributeError, TimeoutError) as err:
    SERVER_ssh.close()
    exit('Connection to SERVER fails')

with SSHClientInteraction(SERVER_ssh, timeout=20, display=True, buffer_size=8192) as interact:
    interact.send(command)
    time.sleep(2)
    interact.expect(r'(.+)')
    cmd_output_ssh = interact.current_output_clean

SERVER_ssh.close()
```

Comment: What command are you running?

Answer (score 1):

`SSHClientInteraction` constructor has `tty_height` parameter, which defaults to 24.

(assuming you use [`paramiko-expect` library](https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect))